# Modify Tensorflow (Keras) Optimizer (for Layerwise Learning Rate Multipliers)

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am trying to train a CNN in tensorflow (keras) with different learning rates per layer. As this option is not included in tensorflow i am trying to modify an already existing optimizer like suggested in this [github comment](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/5920#issuecomment-328890905).

When I simply copy the source code of the SGD optimizer that i found in

> "C:\Users\user\Anaconda3\envs\tf_gpu\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow_core\python\keras\optimizers.py"

(without any modifications) into my script and I try to run it I get the following error:

```
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-2-757ea125a090> in <module>
----> 1 opti = SGD(lr=0.001, momentum=0.9, nesterov=False)

<ipython-input-1-dad895e21911> in __init__(self, lr, momentum, decay, nesterov, **kwargs)
     63 
     64   def __init__(self, lr=0.01, momentum=0., decay=0., nesterov=False, **kwargs):
---> 65     super(SGD, self).__init__(**kwargs)
     66     with K.name_scope(self.__class__.__name__):
     67       self.iterations = K.variable(0, dtype='int64', name='iterations')

TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required positional argument: 'name'
```

Do I need to make modifications directly in the source code and compile tensorflow from source or am I just doing something wrong?

After attempting to install tensorflow (with GPU support) and getting a lot of errors with CuDNN and CUDA I ended up installing it using

```
conda install tensorflow-gpu
```

which worked perfectly, so I am a bit scared to uninstall the now running tensorflow version and compile it from source.

Also, if you know other ways how to modify the learning rate for each layer individually using tensorflow please let me know.

Comment: your change is at the C level so I think you would have to recompile from source

Comment: When modifying just the Python code, there's no need to compile TF from source, so even if you modify the TF Python code that is installed in your PC - you don't need to build it. 

Please share the code you're running.

Couldn't reproduce your error, I copied the SGD implementation, inherited Optimizer and it worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

This could be from a bad implementation.

I solved this by simply adding a name argument `name='sgd'`.

```py
opti = SGD(lr=0.001, momentum=0.9, nesterov=False, name='sgd')
```

Let me know if that works